# Windows 10 Color Management Profile Stopped working

Tags: windows-10, colors, color-profiles

I have an Asus monitor that requires some color calibration. I used XRite Colormunki to calibrate it and it generated a .icm file.

I use Color Management and set its Color Profile as default.

[image]

This used to work fine. But given that I am using a laptop. I often need to re-set it. Usually, I use Win+P to change between single display and dual display and the problem will correct itself. Sometimes I have to bring up the Color Management page and click "Set as Default Profile" again.

But this week, no matter what I do. Color will not change. It is always the unnatural / over-saturated color. No amount of of display change / color management setting can reset it back to my calibrated profile. Reloading the color profile will cause the screen to blink but back to the same profile.

I am running out of ideas.